# How do I stop Airflow from Logging connection string?

Tags: airflow

When I excute command to add a connection uri in Airflow, it echo the username and password:

```sh
airflow connections add 'example_db' \
    --conn-uri 'postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/example_db'
```

Airflow logs:

```sh
 Successfully added `conn_id`=example_db : postgresql://username:userpassword@postgres:5432/example_db
```

How do I mute this output? I don't want `userpassword` logged from the environment variable.

Comment: I wonder if you could route it to `/dev/null`.  eg `airflow connections add 'example_db' \
    --conn-uri 'postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/example_db'  > /dev/null`

Comment: I am an idiot! That was that. Could you write an answer that I can accept?

Comment: Ok, good to hear.  I'll submit an answer

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not aware of any Airflow settings or configs to accomplish this, but you could pipe these commands to `/dev/null`

Example

```
airflow connections add 'example_db' --conn-uri \ 
'postgresql://${POSTGRES_USER}:${POSTGRES_PASSWORD}@postgres:5432/example_db' \ 
> /dev/null
```